# How to animate maxlines property of a RichText widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an expandable textview which is capable of rendering html and css. I've got it all working. But now I have no idea how to **animate** the widget expanding.

I expand the widget by setting the state of `_maxLines`

```
return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RichText(
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: _maxLines,
              text: HTML.toTextSpan(context,
                  widget.htmlContent),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(_buttonText),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if(_maxLines == 5){
                    setState(() {
                      _maxLines = 15;
                    });
                  } 
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        );
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`AnimatedCrossFade`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html) widget to switch between both views.

```dart
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => {setState(() => _showFullText = !_showFullText)},
    child: AnimatedCrossFade(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        crossFadeState: _showFullText ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
        firstChild: Text(
            text,
        ),
        secondChild: Text(
            text,
            maxLines: 2,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: The opacity blending isn't appropriate. Makes the widgets flicker. What curves do we need to keep Child A 100% opacity until the last moment?

Comment: This seems to work `          firstCurve: Curves.easeIn,
          secondCurve: Curves.easeOutExpo,`

Comment: There are all types of curves visualized on this page in case you just guessed the "right" ones: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try AnimatedSwitcher

Some link that might help you

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W7POjFb88g
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-animated-series-animated-opacity-c11137883a8d

https://medium.com/flutter-community/animated-widgets-in-flutter-763fd5dd6d01

Comment: AnimatedCrossFade as used in my answer is actually an AnimatedSwitcher with some defaults already set. You don't really need an AnimatedSwitcher which allows multiple different transitions for this task.